# Activity indicator similar to MBProgressHUD for Titanium

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, mbprogresshud

Is there any activity indicator similar to [**MBProgressHUD**](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD) for **Titanium based iOS application** ?

I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a lot, but didn't get any solution till now.

So I developed a module for integrating an activity indicator similar to `MBProgressHUD` to Titanium based iOS applications (It uses same code and similar functionality .

You can find the module here : [**MMP_Activity**](https://github.com/Midhun-MP/MMP_Activity)

Dedicated to **Stack Overflow** and **Appcelerator** for helping me a lot for getting it right.

Comment: Hello,Can you update this module, so it can support architecture: x86_64? Thanks